# preg_replace() function problem?

Tags: php, regex

Look at this simple script please

```
$a = "test";
echo $b = preg_replace('/[^a](e)/',"<b>$1</b>",$a); // returns <b>e</b>st
```

I want to bold the "e" characters, when there is no "a" character before it.

Logically in `$0` it must match `"te"`, and in `$1` - `"e"`, but why it strips the first character in my example?

I can solve the task in another way, but i want to understand this behavior.

Thanks much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why it strips the first character in my example?

Because the match is *two* characters wide: the `e`, and the character before it (which is denoted by `[^a]`).

To change this, there are two ways. The easy is just to parenthesize your match:

```
echo $b = preg_replace('/([^a])(e)/',"$1<b>$2</b>",$a); // returns t<b>e</b>st
```

The second is to use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

```
echo $b = preg_replace('/(?<!a)(e)/',"<b>$1</b>",$a); // returns t<b>e</b>st
```

Comment: [We're typists first, programmers second.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/11/we-are-typists-first-programmers-second.html)

Comment: @Blair: Practice. ;-) But I don’t actually consider myself a fast typist. Much of the above post was copy/pasted from the question, I only had to make minimal adjustments and add the explanation. *Then* I went and checked whether I had remembered the syntax for negative lookbehind correctly (I rarely ever use id) and added the appropriate link to the answer. Your answer has much more original text than mine, and you linked to the first answer so you probably started answering *after* me.

Comment: I know. I was writing my answer thinking "oh good, I can answer a specific part of the question that hasn't been answered yet". *post* Oh good. Two other people have already answered that. *sigh*

Answer (score 2):

Your error is that `/[^a](e)/` **does not** say to match an "e" when there is no "a" right before it.  Rather, it says match a non-"a" and an "e", and save the "e".

You need `/(?<!a)(e)/`.  That says match an "e" when there is not an "a" right before it, which is what you said you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

[@Coronatus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144762/preg-replace-function-problem/4144786#4144786) gives you the code to fix the problem. The reason that you experience it is as follows:

In `preg_replace('/[^a](e)/',"<b>$1</b>",$a)` the `'/[^a](e)/'` part matches `t` and the `e` in test, but only stores the `e` (it's the only thing you have in brackets). So, when you do the replace, you are replacing the matched section (`te`) with your bolded stored value (`e`). This is why you are losing the first character.

The other option for code is:

```
preg_replace('/([^a])(e)/', '$1<b>$2</b>', $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace('/([^a])e/', '$1<b>e</b>', $a);`